# can we use two list variables to get inputs in terraform and then iterate on the basis on values of lists in a single resource block

Tags: terraform

### I have declared two list variables and in tfvars values are assigned as:

```
    variable  "vmName" {
     description = "Name of VM's to be added for post provisioning tasks"
     type = set(string)
    }
    
    variable "vm_extension_scripts_commands" {
     description = "List of powershell commands to run multiple scripts" 
     type = list(string)
    }
```

---

### tfvars:-- I need to run the below 3 powershell commands in the below vm's (servers):

```
    vmName = ["myVmNew-client1", "myVmNew1"] #servers


    vm_extension_scripts_commands = ["powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File C:\\Provision\\2022\\a.ps1","powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File C:\\Provision\\2022\\b.ps1","powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File C:\\Provision\\2022\\c.ps1"]   #powershell commands to run on above servers
```

---

### Main.tf:---- this is how I am doing, but getting errors

```
    locals {
      servers = var.vmName
      script_commands = var.vm_extension_scripts_commands
      scripts_commands_on_server = flatten([
        for srv in local.servers : [
          for scpt in local.script_commands : {
              servers = srv
              script_commands = scpt
            }
        ]
    ])

    resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "azure_windows_vm_Extension_scripts" {
  
    for_each = { for entry in local.scripts_commands_on_server :  "${entry.servers}.${entry.script_commands}" => entry }

  
    name                 = "azure_vm_post_prov_scripts_${each.value.servers}"
    virtual_machine_id   = var.os_type == "Windows" ? data.azurerm_virtual_machine.example[each.value.servers].id : ""
    publisher            = var.vm_extension_publisher != "" ? var.vm_extension_publisher : "Microsoft.Compute"
    type                 = var.vm_extension_type != "" ? var.vm_extension_type : "CustomScriptExtension"
    type_handler_version = var.vm_extension_type_handler_version != "" ? var.vm_extension_type_handler_version : "1.10"
    auto_upgrade_minor_version = true

    settings = <<SETTINGS
       {
           "Command": "${each.value.script_commands}"
        } 
    SETTINGS
    }
```

---

### Errors: I am getting the below error block for 6 times with all combination of vmName and commands.

```
    Error: "settings" contains an invalid JSON: invalid character 'P' in string escape code#
 
    │   with azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.azure_windows_vm_Extension_scripts["myVmNew-client1.powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File C:\\Provision\\2022\\a.ps1"],
    │   on postprov.tf line 98, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "azure_windows_vm_Extension_scripts":
    │   98:  settings = <<SETTINGS
    │   99:     {
    │  100:         "Command": "${each.value.script_commands}"
    │  101:     } 
    │  102: SETTINGS
```

---

### The problem is:  each.value.servers and each.value.scripts both are containing concatenated values of servers and commands.

I need in the below each.value.servers - it should get server names which are declared in vmName from tfvars

```
    name                 = "azure_vm_post_prov_scripts_${each.value.servers}"
    virtual_machine_id   = var.os_type == "Windows" ? 
    data.azurerm_virtual_machine.example[each.value.servers].id

 

    "Command": "${each.value.script_commands}"
```

---

in the above each.value.script_commands - it should get those 3 commands which are declared in vm_extension_scripts_commands from tfvars.

---

If anyone has similar experience in the past, please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

First, the compound key `"myVmNew-client1.powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File C:\\Provision\\2022\\a.ps1"` is legal terraform, but it's ugly, and you might not be able to reproduce it in a sane way if you need to rebuild state with terraform import, or if you need to refactor this code without triggering a rebuild. Consider using a simpler key.

On the errors you're getting, it looks like the problem isn't the concatenation, but the escaping. You're building `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File C:\\Provision\\2022\\a.ps1`, which escapes (in terraform) down to `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File C:\Provision\2022\a.ps1`. Your JSON parser sees `\P`, and throws an error. Double escape your commands to avoid this:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File C:\\\\Provision\\\\2022\\\\a.ps1
```

Comment: I got your point, thanks for the suggestion. But what really I want is my:  ```each.value.servers``` should hold ```myVmNew-client1``` and ```myVmNew``` during sub-sequent for-each loop iteration   and   ```each.value.scripts.commands``` should hold              ```"powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File C:\\Provision\\2022\\a.ps1"```   ,   ```"powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File C:\\Provision\\2022\\b.ps1"```   and    ```"powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File C:\\Provision\\2022\\c.ps1'' ```

Comment: Then why are you combining both into a flattened list of single entries?

Comment: Since I need to run 3 powershell commands in the mentioned 2 servers. And I am passing servers as list input variable and PowerShell commands as another list with a set of 3 Commands.  The extension block should run  all 3 powershell commands in server ```myNew-client``` first and then the block should run again the same 3 PowerShell commands on server ```myVmNew``` . I didn't get any way to do this, and thought with flattened i can do this.